# VS Code - Alternative for Deploy To Azure Extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-web-app-service, vscode-extensions

I used to use this MS VS Code extension ([Deploy to Azure](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-deploy-azure.azure-deploy)) to publish various webapps to Azure.  I liked it particularly well because you could publish to a specific Deployment Slot (eg. Staging).  Unfortunately, it's now been deprecated and no longer works.  Are there any recommended alternative extensions that can accomplish the same task (deploying to a specific Azure slot)

Comment: One clarification - I do also know how to use the Azure DevOps Pipelines and Git commit and build to a deployment slot.  I'm just looking for a direct publishing option like Deploy to Azure.

Answer (score 1):

As Per this [GitHub-VSCode-Extensions-Update](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-deploy-azure/issues/239),

> Hi! Please note that this extension is being deprecated and will be removed from VS code **[marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-deploy-azure.azure-deploy)** on 11 April 2022.

This also means that "**[Configure CI/CD Workflow](https://github.com/Azure/vscode-aks-tools/tree/d7179a47d4413516e46f19859dac93842f377f82#configure-cicd-workflow)**" and "**B[rowse CI/CD Workflows](https://github.com/Azure/vscode-aks-tools/tree/d7179a47d4413516e46f19859dac93842f377f82#browse-cicd-workflows)**" option will no longer be available on **[Azure Kubernetes Service](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-kubernetes-tools.vscode-aks-tools)** extension.

Please move your workloads away from the extension before 11 April 2022.

As an alternative, you may choose to use **[Starter workflows](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/actions/using-workflows/using-starter-workflows)** from GitHub to quickly onboard your application to GitHub Actions. You may alternatively choose to use **[Create file API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#create-or-update-file-contents)** to create a Actions workflow file and **[Secrets API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/actions#secrets)** to create pre-requisites deployment secrets.

Comment: I'm a little confused by the answer.  The first link (CI/CD Setup...) takes one to the exact same deprecated Deploy to Azure extension that I was referring to.  The other ones don't seem to fit my need of directly publishing a WebApp to a deployment slot.

Comment: @MikeSmith, updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks - I did see that but I'm not using GitHub actions.  I appreciate your help.